In Cloverdx, trying to store fields and then use them to validate the data
In Cloverdx, I have data like this Now I want to store the field names and their data types in a list/variable and then check if the values under field name i.e., if value is Auto Complete and data type is boolean so, is Auto Complete containing a boolean value or not.
I have tried different methods but none of them are working:
sample data
Error:
1
